# Chrome Incognito Mode Settings

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I'd like to change my default search engine when in Incognito mode. Is there a way to do this? I checked in chrome://settings under Advanced and found a way to set my default search engine, but this setting applies to both regular and Incognito mode. I'd like to have two different values; one for regular, one for incognito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search Engine settings are per user in Chrome and shared with the incognito session.

A workaround is to add a different user profile and simply set the default search engine for that profile.

[image]

There is no way to change session from an incognito window, so, you first have to click on the top left hand icon and change users, then launch incognito:

[image]

I know this isn't ideal, but it does appear to work.

Comment: Related -- enabling and then using "Browse as Guest" (3 clicks): http://osxdaily.com/2014/07/14/enable-profile-manager-guest-mode-chrome/.